# Implement Factory pattern with multiple parameters and each parameters are interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-method

I am a little bit confused on Factory Method with multiple parameters in which all parameters can change from GUI by user as seen below picture.
[image]

For each combobox item I have an interface and concrete implementations.

I have a SignalProcessor class which gets parameters as this 3 interfaces as below:

```
public interface ISignalProcessor
{
    double[] Process(double[] data);
}

public class SignalProcessor : ISignalProcessor
{
    private IFft _fft;

    private IWindowing _windowing;

    private IInverseSpectrum _inverseSpectrum;

    private IDecimation _decimation;

    public SignalProcessor(IWindowing windowing, IFft fft,  IInverseSpectrum inverseSpectrum, IDecimation decimation)
    {
        _windowing = windowing;
        _fft = fft;
        _inverseSpectrum = inverseSpectrum;
        _decimation = decimation;
    }

    public double[] Process(double[] data)
    {
        var windowingResult = _windowing.Calculate(data);
        var fftResult = _fft.Calculate(windowingResult);
        var inverseSpectrumResult = _inverseSpectrum.Calculate(fftResult);
        return _decimation.Calculate(inverseSpectrumResult);
    }
}
```

I decided to produce and use concrete classes according to the selected combobox values so the following factory class created.

```
  public static class FactorySP
{
    public static ISignalProcessor Create(string windowingType, int fftSize, bool isInverse, string decimationType)
    {
        return new SignalProcessor(CreateWindowing(windowingType), CreateFft(fftSize), CreateInverseSpectrum(isInverse), CreateDecimation(decimationType));
    }

    private static IWindowing CreateWindowing(string windowingType)
    {
        switch (windowingType)
        {
            case "Triangular":
                return new Triangular();
            case "Rectangular":
                return new Rectangular();
            case "Hanning":
                return new Hanning();
        }
    }

    private static IFft CreateFft(int fftSize)
    {
        switch (fftSize)
        {
            case 128:
                return new Fft128();
            case 256:
                return new Fft256();
            case 512:
                return new Fft512();
            default:
                return new FftNull();
        }
    }
    private static IInverseSpectrum CreateInverseSpectrum(bool isInverse)
    {
        if (isInverse)
            return new InverseSpectrumTrue();

        return new InverseSpectrumFalse();
    }

    private static IDecimation CreateDecimation(string decimationType)
    {
        if (decimationType == "RealTimeDecimation")
            return new RealTimeDecimation();

        return new SweepDecimation();
    }
}
```

Then used as follows:

```
_signalProcessor = FactorySP.Create(WindowingType, FftSize, InverseSpectrum, DecimationType);
result = _signalProcessor.Process(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(a => (double)a).ToArray());
```

Is there a better way to get what I want than that? I feel there is something missing in the method I use :) I know Factory method is not like that but otherwise I have to create all combinations and permutations of overload of factory classes. Should I use the builder pattern to create the SignalProcessor object?

Comment: If you do it in MVVM way, the parameter source will be Property, not UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intent and code properly then you rather have an [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) implementation than a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern implementation.

> The Abstract Factory pattern, a class delegates the responsibility of object instantiation to another object via composition.

> The Factory Method pattern uses inheritance and relies on a subclass to handle the desired object instantiation.

[Reference 24th slide](http://www.buyya.com/254/Patterns/Factory-2pp.pdf) | [Detailed discussion about the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns)

Your `FactoryFP` exposes several methods to create multiple different objects (so called object family). Whereas a Factory Method's scope is a single object. And because of this an Abstract Factory can rely on multiple Factory Methods.

---

*"Is there a better way to get what I want than that?"*
As always it depends what do you want.

- Do you want to hide direct object creation possibility? ([Factory method refactoring](https://refactoring.guru/replace-constructor-with-factory-method))
- Do you want to ease complex object creation? ([Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern))
- Do you want to have an easy to read complex object creation interface? ([Fluent interface pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html))
- etc.

Comment: Thank you that is what I am looking for.