# Factory Method and Log writer class

Tags: c#, factory-method

I Have this class want to practice how to write a factory method pattern

and I can change the `logPlace` by set the app.config,

and I try to improve the performance so I use static `List<string>`,I want to decrease IO loading

Here is my question

1. This class can call factory method pattern or not?
2. Is my code as clear as it could be?
3. I think the `LogBoth` class can be much better, but I have no idea how to improve it.

```cs
   public enum LogLevel
    {
        Error, Debug, Info, Fatal
    }
    static class Msg
    {
        public static List<string> msgList = new List<string>();
    }
    public class LogHelper
    {
        public static ILog Create()
        {
            string logPlace = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPlace"];
            switch (logPlace)
            {
                case "DB":
                    return new LogDB();
                case "File":
                    return new LogFile();
                case "Both":
                    return new LogBoth();
                default:
                    return new LogFile();
            }
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
    public interface ILog
    {
        void WriteLog(string msg);
        void ExecWrite(LogLevel logLevel);
    }
    public class LogDB : ILog
    {
        public LogDB()
        {
            Msg.msgList.Clear();
        }
        public void WriteLog(string msg)
        {
            Msg.msgList.Add(msg);
        }
        public void ExecWrite(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public class LogFile : ILog
    {
       
        private static object _lockObject = new object();

        public LogFile()
        {
            Msg.msgList.Clear();
        }

        public void WriteLog(string msg)
        {
            Msg.msgList.Add(msg);
        }
        public void ExecWrite(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            try
            {
                Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry(1).Execute(()=>WriteToFile(logLevel));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogDB logDB = new LogDB();
                logDB.ExecWrite(logLevel);
            }
        }

        private void WriteToFile(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
               
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                    {
                        foreach (string msg in Msg.msgList)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} [{1}] {2}", DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(08).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), logLevel, msg));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public class LogBoth : ILog
    {
        public LogBoth()
        {
            Msg.msgList.Clear();
        }
        public void ExecWrite(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            LogDB logDB = new LogDB();
            LogFile logFile = new LogFile();

            logDB.ExecWrite(logLevel);
            logFile.ExecWrite(logLevel);
        }

        public void WriteLog(string msg)
        {
            Msg.msgList.Add(msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my observations:

#### LogLevel

- `LogLevel`: Usually the industry calls this [Severity Levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level). I would suggest to try to follow these and do not re-invent the wheel.
  In some cases it might worth to differentiate these two concepts:

  - Log Severity: The seriousness / weight / riskiness of a given event.
  - Log Level: Usually there is a particular order between the levels. The logger should log everything which is at a given level or above

    - For example: if you have this ordering: `Debug` > `Information` > `Warning`
      and you set the level to `Information` then `Debug` logs will be omitted
      from persistence.

#### Msg

- `Msg`: Please try to avoid using abbreviations or short-forms in case of class names.
- `msgList`: Please try to avoid [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).
- `Msg.msgList`: This seems quite clumsy and stuttering.

  - Please try to come up with better naming and encapsulation.

#### LogHelper

- `LogHelper`: This is a `LoggerFactory`. If you have only just `static` members then mark your class `static` as well. By the way this is more like an abstract factory than a factory method.

  - Please read [this related discussion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250222).
- `throw new NullReferenceException`: It is really rare to throw `NullReferenceException` manually. And fortunately this is not needed at all. You have at least two options:
- single return statement:

```cs
ILog logger;
switch (logPlace)
{
    case "DB":
        logger = new LogDB();
        break;
    case "File":
        logger = new LogFile();
        break;
    case "Both":
        logger = new LogBoth();
        break;
    default:
        logger = new LogFile();
        break;
}

return logger;
```

or switch expression (in case of C# 8):

```cs
return logPlace switch
{
    "DB" => new LogDB(),
    "File" => new LogFile(),
    "Both" => new LogBoth(),
    _ => new LogFile(),
};
```

#### ILog

- `ILog`: This should be `ILogger` to be precise.
- `void WriteLog(string msg)`: Usually here should the logger receive the log level / severity. Or it has several overloads with different severity levels, like `LogInformation`, `LogWarning`, `LogError`, etc.

  - Usually loggers can accept any arbitrary data (in a form of `object`) to give the ability to include/attach any useful information to the event.
- `void ExecWrite(LogLevel logLevel)`: Usually this is called `Flush`.

  - And usually there are some automation behind the scenes, which calls
    this periodically or when the logs count reaches a given threshold.
  - Here you could consider to make this function asynchronous to take
    advantage of async I/O (file and database writes are usually support
    async I/O)

#### LogDb

- `LogDb`: Yet again naming: `DatabaseLogger` would be way better in my opinion.
- `Msg.msgList.Clear()`: This could be quite error-prone if you call it inside the ctor. Image the following situation: You have created a `LogDb` and wrote some log into it then you create a `LogFile`. Now all your logs are now gone.
- `LogDb`'s`ExecWrite`: It might make sense to use `NotSupportedException` if you have no willing to implement it. But in that case the whole class does not make too much sense.

#### LogFile

- `LogFile`: `FileLogger` as a naming alternative.
- `LogFile`' `ExecWrite`: This whole retry logic is quite naive. For example if the file path is invalid (pointing to a non-existing file or folder) then retrying the same action would not change anything.

  - With the current implementation of `LogDb` your `catch` block does
    not make any sense.
  - Also you are swallowing the exception
    without logging the fact that something went wrong.
- <s>`WriteToFile`: What if the file does not exists? Why do you use `FileShare.ReadWrite`? Why don't use async I/O?</s>
- `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(08)`: This hard-coded time-zone handling makes your utility hard to maintain and even harder to make it reusable.

  - Also please bear in mind that all events will have the same timestamp
    that are written to the file at the same time. A better approach
    would be to add the timestamp to your log message at the time when
    the consumer of your API calls the `WriteLog` method.

#### LogBoth

- `LogBoth`: `DatabaseAndFileLogger` as a naming alternative.
- `LogBoth`'s `ExecuteWrite`: Here you have determined the ordering. If you have to change that then you have create a new class or create an overload.

  - If you would use async I/O then you could take advantage of concurrent persistence calls.
  - In the industry standard loggers there is no such thing like this. The consumer of your API can set up multiple **sink**s (persistence storage) in configuration file and the logger will take care of them.
  - It is quite challenging to implement it in the right way, because what should happen if either of them fails?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.